# Does maths use jargon or metalanguage?

Tags: terminology

Would mathematics teachers use jargon or metalanguage when teaching their subject?  I assumed the former but may well be wrong.

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example? That would make it much easier to answer your question. Also, why do you think it could be metalanguage?

Comment: Maybe they use metajargon?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematics teachers would have to use both jargon and metalanguage to teach mathematics.

Check out the Wikipedia definition of "jargon": "the technical terminology or characteristic idiom of a special activity occupational or social group."  For example, biology has its own jargon. Witness terms like ["eukaryotes"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eukaryotes) ["prokaryotes"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prokaryotes?s=t) and so on.

Mathematics has its own jargon too. Even those among us who hardly use any math on the job probably remember some mathematical jargon from high school:   "sine," "cosine," "hypotenuse," "parabola," etc.

Math instructors would have to teach the meanings of terms from mathematical jargon, and in doing so would have to use metalanguage. Metalanguage is a language or vocabulary used to talk about language. In other words, it's language about language. For example, in the sentences below a) is not metalanguage but b) is.

> a) The sun came up yesterday.
>   b) "unglaublich" is a German word that translates as "unbelievable."

At this point someone might claim that the two sentences represent the same kind of language. The problem with this claim is that "unglaublich" is neither an English word nor a noun phrase. So if we admit that sentence b) makes sense, then we have to admit that language-about-language has some rules that are distinct from those of non-meta-language--in this instance, distinct rules about what can qualify as a noun phrase.

So now we come to the day in mathematics class when the teacher tells his students the following:  "The hypotenuse is the longest side of a right triangle."

By defining a term, the teacher is using metalanguage. From then on, the teacher uses "hypotenuse" freely with his math students in sentences like "The square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the two other sides of a right triangle." This illustrates a math teacher's necessary use of jargon.